# Adding a background image to a levelplot

Tags: r, lattice, levelplot

I'd like to make a `levelplot` which has a background image. The following code promts the error message `Error in rasterImage(image, x[1], y[1], x[length(x)], y[length(y)]) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet` - apparently `rasterImage` does not recognize printed `levelplot` object as a plot. What's the appropriate method instead of `rasterImage`?

```
library("png")
library("lattice")
library("latticeExtra")

MyFunction <- function(x,y){
  return(
    dnorm(sqrt(x^2+y^2))
    )
}

meshstep <- 0.2
x<- seq(-20,20,meshstep)
y <-seq(-20,20,meshstep)

image <- readPNG("imagepath\\image.png")

grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)

grid$z<- MyFunction(grid$x,grid$y)

MyPalette <- colorRampPalette(c('white','yellow', 'red'))

levels <- 10
p<- levelplot(z~x*y, grid, cuts = levels, xlab="",
          ylab="",
          colorkey = TRUE, region = TRUE,col.regions=MyPalette(levels+1),
alpha.regions=0.3)


plot(p)
rasterImage(image, x[1], y[1],x[length(x)],y[length(y)])
```

Comment: You are trying to mix two different plotting paradigms. The coordinate systems will need to be matched. See the documentation in packages "gridBase" and "latticeExtra" for background information that will be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `+.trellis` and `layer` combined with `grid.raster`:

```
library(grid)
library(latticeExtra)
library(png)

image <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))

p + layer(grid.raster(as.raster(image)), under=TRUE)
```

Comment: When running this code, I get no errors, but just a `levelplot` with low alpha, and the plot doesn't have the background image I want. Why could that be?

Comment: I have fixed the code. Try it again. Anyhow, it is difficult to know what is your result without a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Unfortunately, I couldn't manage to get the above code working, even after I added x, y, width and height values, i.e. using `layer(grid.raster(as.raster(image)), x[1], y[1],x[length(x)],y[length(y)], under=TRUE) `, I got an error message on not having enough memory. I opted to solve this problem with a different approach, namely fetching an actual map instead using a handpicked png. The following thread had valuable information for doing that: http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Use-a-PNG-image-as-background-for-lattice-plotting-with-rasterVis-td7584893.html Thanks!

Comment: Ok, but note that your parentheses are in the wrong places and the arguments of `grid.raster` are different from `rasterImage`. It should be `layer(grid.raster(as.raster(image), x=myX, y=myY, width=myWidth, height=myWidth), under=TRUE)`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It might or might not have been the source of some errors - I didn't paste the code snippet from an actual file, but tried to reconstruct what I had done. Anyway, in a recent second compiling attempt, I managed to get your answer working, but I didn't try it with my particular image since my alternative approach was already producing nicer results.